# Dialog Box Variable -- No Entry Added to DoDataExchange()

Tags: c++, mfc, dynamic-data-exchange

After working in C# for years, I've returned to an old MFC application I wrote. But it looks like I need a refresher on a few things.

I added a check box control to an existing dialog box. I then used Class Wizard to add a non-control variable of type `bool`. The variable was created as expected.

However, I see no entry was added to the `DoDataExchange()` method. And when I tried adding it manually:

```
DDX_Check(pDX, IDC_PRINT_SUMMARY, m_bPrintSummary);
```

I get the IntelliSense error:

> a reference of type "int &" (not const-qualified) cannot be initialized with a value of type "bool"

**1.** Why wasn't an entry in `DoDataExchange()` created for me when I added the variable?

**2.** If `DDX_Check()` expects and `int &`, why did Class Wizards default to type `bool` for a checkbox value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A check box can be one of three values, hence the need for the int.

`BST_CHECKED` - Button is checked.

`BST_INDETERMINATE` - Button is grayed, indicating an indeterminate state (applies only if the button has the BS_3STATE or BS_AUTO3STATE style).

`BST_UNCHECKED` - Button is cleared

As to why it's not auto editing the DoDataExchange, it's probably an issue with the C++ formatting of your class.

Comment: So then my question still stands: Why does the variable for a checkbox default to a `bool`?

Comment: It's a bug. I think it used to default to BOOL, which would've worked fine (if a little misleading).